# Ansible apt module - "unsupported parameter for module: “name"

Tags: ansible

Ansible version 2.1.2.0 (homebrew, macOS - having removed any previous versions)

```
ansible myserver -m apt -a “name=backup2l,state=present” --ask-pass
```

returns this error:

```
myserver | FAILED! => {
    "changed": false,
    "failed": true,
    "msg": "unsupported parameter for module: “name"
}
```

This seems the correct syntax according to [the examples](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/apt_module.html#examples):

```
# Install the package "foo"
- apt: name=foo state=present
```

I've tried wrapping the values for `name` and `state` in single quotes, also using a space between the parameters (it doesn't like that – "ERROR! Missing target hosts").

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to using “smart quotes” rather than "regular quotes", which was caused by typing a command out in my notes application first then copying and pasting into iTerm.

NB: the error message you get depends on what you're trying to do - if you're running a single command with `-a`, Ansible will say "No such file or directory".

**Solution for Mac users:**

System Preferences > Keyboard > Text > uncheck "Use smart quotes and dashes".

Vote for this if you like: [iTerm2 feature request](https://gitlab.com/gnachman/iterm2/issues/5238)

Answer (score 0):

ansible arguments are seperated by spaces like a command line, not a function call.

Try:

```
ansible myserver -m apt -a “name=backup2l state=present” --ask-pass
```

Comment: It was a quote problem. Thanks anyway.